# how can I run a truffle test in a debugger?

Tags: truffle, testing

as a developer I want to run my javascript test in a debugger so as to be able to step through tests and inspect the values of variables.

The goal is to run it in a Mocha debug mode

Comment: I would like to run the JavaScript test in debug mode not the contract

Comment: apparently I had a reading skills fail.  sorry about that.

Comment: There is a solution - it is possible to use node inspector to debug tests (as well as IDEs such as VSCode). I posted the details about node inspector here - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/43633/36407

Comment: 5 people marked as duplicate, but the question is different.@DrGorb `test is debug mode` as opposed to debugging the contract.

Comment: I switched to [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) because of this issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the way Truffle interacts with Mocha's API (i.e. [programmatically](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically)), there are only a handful of options we can specify in the `mocha` config in our `truffle.js` file (`grep, ui, reporter, timeout, bail, useColors, retries, slow, ignoreLeaks, fullTrace`).

I would also like this functionality, so I raised [the issue over at the Mocha repo](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2762).

Note that this is not a direct answer to your question, but I can't comment in this stackexchange forum due to my current reputation level; just wanted to share my research.

Comment: It's been one year and a half. No updates in the meantime?

Comment: @PaulBerg look at the comments on the original post. Something over here may help you: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41094/debugging-js-unit-tests-with-truffle-framework-in-vs-code/43633#43633

Comment: I switched to [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) because of this