# How can I debug a truffle JS unit test with vscode?

Tags: truffle, testing, mocha, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code and truffle and would like to easily debug my JavaScript tests.

A similar question has been asked here: [how can I run a truffle test in a debugger?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/14031). This has been wrongly marked as a duplicated and not been released.

Comment: This similar answer, using truffle-core, worked for me: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/41096/3708

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the following to your configurations in `launch.json`:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "run tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js",
            "args": ["test"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/test/**/*"
            ],
          }
    ]
```

You will need to adjust the `program` property to match the path of your installed truffle if you have installed truffle globally.

Comment: That doesn't seem to run the tests for me.

Comment: It worked for me after I installed truffle as a local package

Comment: You may want to add the network (configured in `truffle-config.js`) to the arguments, like, assuming you called your network `develop`:
`"args": ["test", "--network", "develop"],`

Also, you can just use the truffle executable instead of `cli.bundled.js` in the "program" section; I have found it running `which truffle` from shell.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, if you have installed truffle globally (`npm install -g truffle`), you will need to provide the full path of that directory e.g.:
`"program": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js"`